# Error de violacion de segmento

Tags: c++

EL objetivo de mi código es devolver la posición que ocupa un elemento x en la lista:

```
Position es un tipo de dato int
l es un puntero a una lista enlazada
x es el elemnto que queremos encontrar
```

```
Position listLocate (ListPtr l, Element x){
    Position contador, posicion = NOPOS;
    ListNodePtr aux;

    if (l != nullptr){
        aux = l->head;
        contador = 1;

        while (aux->key != x){
            if(aux != nullptr && posicion == NOPOS){
                if(aux->key == x){
                    posicion = contador;
                }else{
                    aux = aux->next;
                    contador++;
                }   
            }else{
                posicion = NOPOS;
            }
        }
    }
    return posicion;
}
```

Al hacer una prueba del programa me sale una violacion de segmento que no se como arreglar.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while (aux->key != x){
        if(aux != nullptr && posicion == NOPOS){
```

Primero preguntas por `aux->key` y después miras si `aux` apunta a `nullptr`... deberías hacerlo justo al revés.

```
Position contador = -1;

if( l != nullptr )
{
  ListNodePtr aux = l->head;
  contador = 0;

  while( aux != nullptr )
  {
    if( aux->key == x ) break;

    contador++;
    aux = aux->next;
  }

  if( aux == nullptr )
  {
    contador = -1; // No encontrado
  }
}

return contador;
```

Comment: mil graciaas :)